# Is there a way to let Applescript type what you say?

Tags: macos, applescript, speech

I think I'm not doing this right, this is what I have...

```
tell application "SpeechRecognitionServer"
    with timeout of (1.0E+9 * 100000000) seconds
        set theResponse to listen for text returned of {say "What do I have to type for you?"} with timeout of 30 seconds
        end timeout
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke (theResponse)
        end tell
    end timeout
end tell
```

I want to let Applescript type what I say, so if I say "Hello", that Applescript with type "Hello" etc

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with `SpeechRecognitionServer` but there's a workaround using Dictation in Mountain Lion and higher.

Enable Dictation and run this, it shows a dialog with a text field as "listener",
after finishing dictation press `return`. TextEdit will be opened and the text typed.

```
say "What do I have to type for you?" using "Alex"
set theResponse to text returned of (display dialog "Press 'fn' twice and speak!" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Ok"} default button 2)
activate application "TextEdit"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke theResponse
```